# Searching and writing

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to write a program which looks for words with the same three middle characters(each word is 5 characters long) in a list, then writes them into a file like this :

```
wasdy
casde
tasdf

gsadk
csade
hsadi
```

Between the similar words i need to leave an empty line. I am kinda stuck.
Is there a way to do this? I use Python 3.2 .

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I dunno why does it put an enter between gsadk and csade.

Comment: give us some code to start from...

Comment: Do you mean same three middle characters, in order?  Or just same three middle characters?

Answer (score 2):

I would use the [`itertools.groupby`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) function for this. Assuming `wordlist` is a list of the words you want to group, this code does the trick.

```
import itertools

for k, v in itertools.groupby(wordlist, lambda word: word[1:4]):
    # here, k is the key the words are grouped by, i.e. word[1:4]
    # and v is a list/iterable of the words in the group
    for word in v:
        print word
    print
```

`itertools.groupby(wordlist, lambda word: word[1:4])` basically takes all the words, and groups them by `word[1:4]`, i.e. the three middle characters. Here's the output of the above code with your sample data:

```
wasdy
casde
tasdf

gsadk
csade
hsadi
```

Comment: you should sort the data before using `groupby`

Answer (score 1):

To get you started: try using the builtin `sorted` function on the list of words, and for the key you should experiment with using a `slice(1, 4)`.

For example:

```
some_list = ['wasdy', 'casde', 'tasdf', 'gsadk', 'other', 'csade', 'hsadi']
sorted(some_list, key = lambda x: sorted(x[1:4]))
# outputs ['wasdy', 'casde', 'tasdf', 'gsadk', 'csade', 'hsadi', 'other']
```

***edit:***  It was unclear to me whether you wanted "same three middle characters, in order" or just "same three middle characters".  If the latter, then you could look at `sorted(some_list, key = lambda x: x[1:4])` instead.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
from collections import defaultdict
dict_of_words = defaultdict(list)
for word in list_of_words:
    dict_of_words[word[1:-1]].append(word)
```

then, to write to an output file:

```
with open('outfile.txt', 'w') as f:
    for key in dict_of_words:
        f.write('\n'.join(dict_of_words[key])
        f.write('\n' )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
word_list = ['wasdy', 'casde','tasdf','gsadk','csade','hsadi']

def test_word(word):
    return all([x in word[1:4] for x in ['a','s','d']])

f = open('yourfile.txt', 'w')
f.write('\n'.join([word for word in word_list if test_word(word)]))
f.close()
```

returns:

```
wasdy
casde
tasdf
gsadk
csade
hsadi
```